# for each loop with increase array

Tags: ruby, arrays, foreach

I am trying to iterate through an array using a for each loop in ruby but inside of the loop I am increasing the size of the array conditionally. I want to iterate through the array until I have run the iterate with every element in the array including all the ones I have added

```
for x in fol
    t = get_transition(x,"")
    for i in t
        if i != nil && !fol.include?(i)
            fol = fol.push(i)
            fol = fol.flatten
        end
    end
end
```

In the first loop of this code the array

```
fol = [1]
```

and it adds the element 3 to the array creating

```
fol = [1, 3]
```

It will then run the loop again with x = 3 and the array becomes

```
fol = [1, 3, 2]
```

But it will not iterate again with x = 2.
Thank you in advance for any assistance

For clarification purposes I have added in print statements and the output that they generate.

```
fol.each do |x|
    puts "fol = #{fol}"
    puts "x = #{x}"
    t = get_transition(x,"")
    puts "t = #{t}"
    t.each do |i|
        puts "i = #{i}"
        if i != nil && !fol.include?(i)
            fol = fol.push(i)
            fol = fol.flatten
        end
    end
end

puts "\nfol = #{fol}"
```

This code generates this output

```
fol = [1]
x = 1
t = [3]
i = 3
fol = [1, 3]
x = 3
t = [2]
i = 2

fol = [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: How does it go from `[1,3]` to `[1,3,2]` when `x=3`? What do you mean by, "it will not iterate again with x = 2"? It would be helpful if you could (edit to) give an example for `get_transition`, and the associated desired output.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think the 2 is added in the `x=3` iteration by `fol.push(i)`. The problem is that it doesn't continue to the `x=2` iteration.

Comment: I should add that this code is very confusing, especially the part where you reassign `fol` inside the loop. It needs a total rewrite to be more idiomatic, but I can't tell from the context what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes the get_transition(3,"") returns 2 which is then added to the array

Comment: What would you recommend in order to increase the readability. I need to reassign fol inside the loop because I need to iterate over all the elements that are added.

Comment: What is the meaning of `fol`? What are you trying to make and what are you trying to use it for? There is probably a *much* cleaner and shorter way to do it.

Comment: Well I tried running your code (using a simple `get_transition` method) and it _did_ iterate over `x=2`. What Ruby version are you running? Can you post full code that we can actually run?

Comment: fol is simply an array of number (which represent states).

Comment: You may think that `get_transition` is irrelevant, but without it we cannot run your code and compare results. If `get_transition` is a complex method, could you give us a simplified version of it?

Comment: I am running ruby 1.9.3 and I can post the entire code but it is rather long

Comment: You can use a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) to share large code samples.

Comment: Here is the gist link                                                                                                                 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46c0cd1ae1ce76dfab23                             If that is easier for you to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to iterate through an array using a for each loop in ruby
>   but inside of the loop I am increasing the size of the array
>   conditionally. I want to iterate through the array until I have run
>   the iterate with every element in the array including all the ones I
>   have added

Why not just treat this as a queue? That's pretty much what you've described

```
queue = fol.clone
until queue.empty?
  x = queue.pop
  t = get_transition(x,"")
  for i in t
    if i != nil && !fol.include?(i)
       # Not too sure what type "i" is here, but you push onto the queue here
       # I'd try to avoid flattening if you know what your data types are as it will be slow
    end
  end
end
```